# IE (6 & 7) iFrame Querystring Parameters Set In .NET MVC Page Not Working, Seemed Stripped, But Appear In Tact On Page Source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iframe

We're using .NET MVC, and we're trying to dynamically (through the controller) set the iFrame's URL.  This worked fine on FireFox and Chrome, but not Ie.  On Ie only the first case site lets the user log through correctly.  The v10 and v9 sites don't.  All sites use querystring params to log in.  Their source looks like this (unsuccessful source in IE) - no visible difference.

- Also, we tried that whole IE7 Security setting Enabled for navigating to frame within another domain - that wasn't the problem; it still doesn't work. Also doesn't work on IE6. Same results as in the screenshots below.
- Also Html Encoding hasn't worked (not shown, but tried).

Any ideas would be so awesome!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title>
<style type="text/css">
        td  {
              font-family: Arial;
              font-size: small;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Account/Navigate" method="post">
    <table style="align: right; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="WN" />&nbsp;

                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="MyDg" />

                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="V9" />

             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <iframe id="displayFrame" src="http://my.totallyinsecuretopostthis.com/Login.aspx?&uname=sdavis&pword=04ab" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

successful source in IE7:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1"><title>

</title>
<style type="text/css">
            td  {
                    font-family: Arial;
                    font-size: small;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/Account/Navigate" method="post">
    <table style="align: right; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="WN" />

                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="MyDg" />

                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="V9" />

             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <iframe id="displayFrame" src="http://www.totallyinsecuretopostthis.com/users/428/login/700bc1c8d837f30fdbc03cfc03b58c02" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Code snippet (first View, then Controller):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SingleSignOnUser>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Wingnut.Data.Model"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    td  {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: small;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Navigate", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <% TempData["username"] = Model.WingnutUserEmail; %>
    <% TempData["password"] = Model.PasswordHash; %>
    <table style="align: right; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                <!-- always display this, but when click, make sure you are authenticated; else, prompt for correct 
                 wingnut password -->
                <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="WN" />&nbsp;
                <% if (Model.IsV10User()) { %>
                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="MyDg" />
                <% } %>
                <% if (Model.IsV9User()) { %>
                    <input type="submit" name="butSubmit" value="V9" />
                <% } %>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <% string url = ViewData["iFrameURL"].ToString(); %>
    <% if (ViewData["iFrameURL"].ToString() != "popup") { %>
        <iframe id="displayFrame" src="<%=ViewData["iFrameURL"]%>" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;"></iframe>
    <% } %>
```

(now Controller code:)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Navigate(string butSubmit) {
    _service = new SSOUserService();
    SingleSignOnUser wnUser = _service.GetValidUser(TempData["username"].ToString(), TempData["password"].ToString());

    ViewData["iFrameURL"] = "http://www.usatoday.com";

    try {
        //if you are supposed to bypass the intersect page...
        if (wnUser != null) {
            switch (butSubmit) {
                case "WN":
                    if (wnUser.IsWingnutUser())
                        ViewData["iFrameURL"] = string.Format("http://www.totallyinsecuretopostthis.com/users/{0}/login/{1}", wnUser.WingnutId, wnUser.WingnutToken);
                    else {
                        // do popup to capture this person's correct, but uncaptured, Wingnut password
                        // try to authenticate, if can, save, and proceed
                        // else, give error message / popup finally
                        ViewData["iFrameURL"] = "popup";
                        ViewData["popupText"] = "Oops. During the Totallyinsecuretopostthis's recent Single Sign On effort, we require that you enter your Totallyinsecuretopostthis" +
                            "password for us here one time only for authentication to SomePlace:";
                    }
                    break;

                case "MyDg":
                    if (wnUser.IsV10User()) {
                        ViewData["iFrameURL"] =
                            string.Format(@"http://my.totallyinsecuretopostthisv10.com/Login.aspx?&uname={0}&pword={1}",
                                          wnUser.V10UserCredentials.LoginName,
                                          wnUser.V10UserCredentials.Password);
                    }
                    break;

                case "V9":
                    if (wnUser.IsV9User()) {
                        ViewData["iFrameURL"] =
                            string.Format(
                                @"https://login.totallyinsecuretopostthisv9.com/clients/OtherPages/ExternalSignIn.aspx?UserName={0}&Password={1}",
                                wnUser.V9UserCredentials.LoginName, wnUser.V9UserCredentials.Password);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Errors", ex.Message);
    }

    return View("Navigation", wnUser);
}
```

---

Comment: Hi, Mehrdad.

I tried encoding it Both in the code behind / controller, As Well as in the View as your example demonstrates below - no luck.  It still doesn't work.  Good idea, though. We have a working theory that it must be encoding somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a hack / resolution - I never did get the iFrame src="mystring" to work, but I did create a hack. B/c the site we're trying to navigate to, we own; so on that site we created a 'mirror' page. The pages look identical

1 - my original page with the iFrame, but not I have an HREF, and when you click to go where I originally wanted...

2 - you hit that login page, and are logged in... but I added querystring params to this login page (we also own this site), and if sso=true, and you are authenticated, you are redirected to...

3 - a page on the Site B with an iFrame that looks identical to the page on Step #1.

It's a hack, and a lot more work, but it 'works,' and is the best for the user's experience that we could ultimately create.

*** Thank you to you guys who provided answers, as well as anyone looking. I appreciate the help so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode` to encode the ampersand in the URL:

```
ViewData["iFrameUrl"] = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode( string.Format( ... ) );
```

I would suggest doing it while rendering the `<a>` tag in the view instead of hardcoding it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something to do with the "?&" at the beginning of the querystring?

Try just: http://my.totallyinsecuretopostthis.com/Login.aspx?uname=sdavis&pword=04ab

Comment: That's what I thought, too - IE doesn't like that syntax, but that wasn't the issue.

Finally I found a hack / resolution - I never did get the iFrame src="mystring" to work, but I did create a hack.  B/c the site we're trying to navigate to, we own; so on that site we created a 'mirror' pg.